# Тестирование приложения на реальном устройстве

Tags: xcode, тестирование

Вопрос покажется довольно глупым, но для меня это пока что сложно. ) Так вот, как сохранить написанное приложение в xcode, чтобы можно было закинуть готовый файл в Iphone и протестировать?

Comment: Открываете поисковик и почти любой тутор по xCode.
Например, [так][1] и читаете/смотрите.
Без учётки разработчика, только симулятор.

  [1]: https://www.google.ru/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4+ios&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=_HG2VL7XFa6WwAOAsYCABg

Answer (score 1):

В топ меню: `Product` > `Archive`,
а если подключить iphone через кабель и на нем установлены соответствующие provision profile, то можно дебажить прямо на нем как при запуске эмулятора

Comment: у меня пункт меню Product > Archive неактивен

Comment: чтоб он стал активен, надо выбрать в списке устройств/симуляторов реальное устройство, либо 'generic iOS device' если устройства нет.